# Adding and removing ToolStripMenuItem's from MenuStrip and DropDownItems in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem

I have `MenuStrip` with some static items. To this `MenuStrip` I am adding items programmatically. Some of these items has child items (`DropDownItems`).

At some point I would like to remove all added items to recreate menu with different items. How to do it right?

Example situation:

```
mainMenu
 -staticItem1
 -added1
  -added1_sub1
  -added1_sub2
 -added2
  -added2_sub1
```

I could do:

```
added1.Dispose();
mainMenu.Items.Remove(added2);
```

Both of this works, but I am not sure if it's safe. Maybe I should remove and dispose all items and subitems one by one recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `Remove` method only, it's enough
- You don't need recursive, When you remove a parent all its children will be removed
- Use `Items.Clear()` to remove all the children for the Menu and 
  `DropDownItems.Clear()` to remove all the children for an item.

Comment: I can't see in Reflector that `Remove` disposes an item. I saw that disposing an item will remove attached events eg. on item click, so the item could be collected by GC. Will item be collected by GC after calling `Remove` on that collection?

Comment: Yes, In your case, you don't need to call Dispose, the item will be removed from memory when the GC finds it convenient.

Comment: OK, but I am still wondering about `Click` event. I think I should unsubscribe from this event, because GC will not collect it. Am I right?

Comment: No, you don't need to unsubscribe the events handlers, Because this reference is only one way.  So, nothing related to the event handler will stop the GC.

Comment: It seems you're still worried, check read http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/3c5552ea-4241-46b4-b1cf-c8b9ee9c639b/  ,Read about Dispose method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=VS.71%29.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28VS.71%29.aspx