# How to prevent adding item more than once at MenuStrip in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, menustrip

I am using menuStrip in windows form application and I want to add available ports as a subMenu programatically. I used mouseHover to do this but it adds the same items in every hoving action.I mean it adds item in every hoving action. How can I prevent this and achieve to add items(ports) once.

Here is my code;

```
   String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

private void cOMToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in ports)
        {
            ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(item);
            cOMToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about clearing all the items before adding them?

Comment: why don't you do that on form's `Load` event?

Comment: If you're not sure about the code for clearing, here is a helpful link: [Adding and removing ToolStripMenuItem's from MenuStrip and DropDownItems in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4041900/6741868)

Comment: Are you sure you want to populate the menu on hover? Maybe you could just do it during initialization or whenever you "get port names". Anyway, you can clear your items every time or, in case you have other items there, remove only the ports (you can use the `Tag` property to mark them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void cOMToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cOMToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count > 0)
        return;

    foreach (var item in ports)
    {
        ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(item);
        cOMToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);
    }
}
```

This way, if items are already added, function will simply return.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void cOMToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cOMToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Clear(); 
    foreach (var item in ports)
    {
        ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(item);
        cOMToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LINQ query to only select the uniques and do the same procedure.

```
string[] uniques = ports.Distinct().ToArray();
```